# Simultaneous open tcp connection using winsock api

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp

Is it possible to implement Simultaneous open tcp connection in c++ . For your kind information i am giving reference of Simultaneous open tcp connection below

http://ttcplinux.sourceforge.net/documents/one/tcpstate/tcpstate.html

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: I certainly hope so, or IIS wouldn't scale worth a crap... Wait a minute...

Answer (score 1):

Based on that state diagram, I see two possibilities:

1) both parties are calling `connect()` at the same time. Since this requires knowing both IP/Port pairs ahead of time, both parties would have to `bind()` to specific IP/Port pairs and then exchange that info with each other (if not hard-coded) before calling `connect()`.

2) one party is calling `listen()` and then `sendto()` with the listening socket while the other party is calling `connect()` at the same time after calling `bind()`.

Either condition is not common in socket programming.  You never have two clients `connect()`'ing to each other, and you rarely if ever send data on a listening socket, you wait for `accept()` to return an established endpoint first and then you send data with that instead.